# VB.NET For loop not running properly

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have been debugging my for loop and I have found that it does not progress through the code it gets to a certain line runs the line comes back to that line once its run and runs it again therefore causing the following error.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>       Parameter name: index

Here's my for loop:

```
For Each user As Data.DataRow In userData.Rows
    If user Is Nothing Then
        Exit For
    End If
    memberList(userId) = New clsMember(user("UserID"), user("Firstname"), user("Secondname"), user("Username"), user("Password"), user("Email"), user("Rights"))
    userId += 1
Next
```

The line it gets stuck on is the following:

```
memberList(userId) = New clsMember(user("UserID"), user("Firstname"), user("Secondname"), user("Username"), user("Password"), user("Email"), user("Rights"))
```

Whilst debugging I found it runs the first time perfectly comes back around to the for loop tries to run it again without getting to the next line:

```
userId += 1
```

And causes the error, I have no idea at all why it is doing this.
If you need any more code I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: What is `memberList(userId).GetUserId()` doing?  It looks like it should return a value but nothings storing it.  When doing a `For Each` the iterator can't be `Nothing` so you don't need the code to exit the for loop.  Is `memberList` already initialized to have the same number of items as `UserData.Rows`?

Comment: My mistake i put that in there for debugging. Ignore that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that userId is >= to memberList.Count

Comment: Suspect userID isn't being initialised, so it's keeping the previous value when it enters the loop the second time. Add `UserID=0` immediately before the 'For..' line

Answer (score 2):

When adding items to a list (assuming it's not yet populated), you can't just pick the index you'd like the item to occupy and assign it a value.  The list needs to have a placeholder there first.

The simplest thing to do is just use [**`List.Add()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add items to your list:

```
For Each user As Data.DataRow In userData.Rows
    memberList.Add(New clsMember(user("UserID"), 
                                 user("Firstname"),
                                 user("Secondname"), 
                                 user("Username"), 
                                 user("Password"), 
                                 user("Email"), 
                                 user("Rights"))
Next
```

Comment: @user3561158, also remember to accept answers that best solve your issue for this and other questions you ask on Stack Overflow